# Alternative to chi-square in evaluating the similarity of two distributions (ordered categorical variables)

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

In my study I compare Finnish and Russian expressions for different parts of the day. I conducted a survey and asked people to refer to a time interval with some non-numeric expression (e.g. if something happens between 1pm and 3pm you might refer to it with the phrase "afternoon"). The thing is that Russian, unlike Finnish, lacks a straight-forward equivalent for *afternoon*. So I am taking the cases where the Finnish informants use the expression *iltapäivä* ('afternoon') and looking at the intervals (pre-specified by me) for which the expression is used to get a distribution, which looks like this (the y axis represents absolute frequency):

[image: the reference distribution]

I do the same for a number of different Russian expressions and then try to compare, which Russian expression is used in the most similar way compared to the Finnish *iltapäivä*. In other words, I try to assess the similarity of different distributions and would like to have a measure by which it would be possible to say that "distribution A is more/less similar to the reference distribution than distribution B". Here are two examples, expressions "vo vtoroj polovine dnja" and "posle obeda"

[image: distributions to compare]

Originally I used a chi-square to do the similarity assessment but I was told that it cannot be applied in a situation like this. So, my question is, what would be a better alternative?

I'm using R to do the analysis. If needed, I can provide a sample data set (because of not having any reputation yet I wasn't able to link it here).

**edit**

To be more precise, the critique I got was that you can't asses the significance of the results when using the chi-square test in this way. E.g. when comparing the distributions for the expressions *iltapäivä* (fist figure) and *posle obeda* (second figure on the left) I get a p-value of  0.4884. When comparing the other groups (vpd and ip) I get  p=0.0005395. What I was told by a reviewer is that I have no way of saying whether 0.4884 is significant or not.

Comment: Do you know why you were told that the Chi-square test cannot be applied?

Comment: Made an edit to clarify this.